# Debugger step through App_Data\CodeRepository

Tags: acumatica

Is there a way to attach the VS Debugger to a local site and have it use & step through the App_Data\CodeRepository source instead of using the PX.Objets.dll file? (For reference & help understanding what's happening 'under the hood')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do what you want, but I propose you a workaround. You can copy/paste code from App_Data\CodeRepository into your project, rename page to your, for example instead ar301000.aspx create page ar301011.aspx and bind it to copy/pasted graph. And now you can debug App_Data\CodeRepository simply and easily. Also if you wish you can even modify it.

Comment: @BitshiftNull does it make sense for you?